# Non-static and Static Methods

Tags: java, arrays, static

i found problems here it says,,

```
non-static method blah blah blah cannot be referenced from a static context
```

which is the function convertToPostfix and convertToInfix is not a static method....

how to fix this, so that i can now compile my code.

```
   public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String n, result;
        char character;
        do {
        character = choiceko();
        switch (character)
        {
            case 'P':
            case 'p': n=numberko("Enter a number: ");
              =======>  result = convertToPostfix(n); <============
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "Infix: " + n + " to Postfix [" +result+"].");
               break;
            case 'I':       
            case 'i': n=numberko("Enter a Number: ");
              =======>  result=convertToInfix(n);<============
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Postfix: " + n + " to Infix [" +result+"].");
                break;
            case 'E':
            case 'e':  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Program Terminated...","Terminated",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                break;              
            default:  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                " Invalid selection. Please Try Again.","ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);           
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Swing? Yes you do have a JOptionPanel but the question itself has no relevance to Swing. Please tag your question more appropriately next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these 2 methods  convertToPostfix and convertToInfix  are non static so you need to create an object of the class and then call these methods.It is because main is static.Lets say your class name is test.Then do like this

```
test t=new test();
t.convertToPostfix(n);
t.convertToInfix(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 =======>  result=convertToInfix(n);<============
```

since you are accessing `convertToInfix`  method in a static context(main method which is static), that method should be a static method.

Solutions:

1) Make `convertToInfix`  method static

or

2) Make an instance of class which have the method `convertToInfix`

```
case 'i': n=numberko("Enter a Number: ");
              ClassOfMethod instance = new ClassOfMethod(); 
              result=instance.convertToInfix(n);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
```

Comment: but if i make it static , it end up in my errors..

Comment: @jarnthrax Updated my post. Look at the second option